# How to validate a field from a BeanItem in Vaadin?

Tags: forms, validation, vaadin

I'm trying my first *Hello World* with [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com) right now and I'm stuck with my first simple **validated Form**. I'm using a `BeanItem` as the `ItemDataSource` for my form, and I don't know how to add a Validator for the bean property.

**My Problem**

How can I get the actual `Field` for the property in my bean? I need to call `addValidator()` on the field, but I can only get it on the `Form`.

**HelloWorldForm**

```
package vaadinapp.hello;

import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItem;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Form;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

public class HelloWorldForm extends Form {
    HelloWorldBean data = new HelloWorldBean();

    public HelloWorldForm() {
        setCaption("Hello World");
        setDescription("This is a simple form that lets you enter your name and displays a greeting.");

        setItemDataSource(new BeanItem(data));

        setFooter(new VerticalLayout());
        getFooter().addComponent(
                new Label("This is the footer area of the Form. You can use any layout here. This is nice for buttons."));
        // Have a button bar in the footer.
        HorizontalLayout okbar = new HorizontalLayout();
        okbar.setHeight("25px");
        getFooter().addComponent(okbar);
        // Add an Ok (commit), Reset (discard), and Cancel buttons
        // for the form.
        Button okbutton = new Button("OK", this, "commit");
        okbar.addComponent(okbutton);
        okbar.setComponentAlignment(okbutton, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);
        okbar.addComponent(new Button("Reset", this, "discard"));
        okbar.addComponent(new Button("Cancel"));
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldBean**

```
package vaadinapp.hello;

public class HelloWorldBean {
    String greeting;

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't add validators to a Property directly. Validators have to be added to the Field itself (fields in a Form or a standalone TexField forexample).

Take a look at the chapter 5.17.3 in the Book of Vaadin for validating a Form: http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.form.html
(Note that there is also getField(id) method in the Form you can use instead of the FieldFactory)

Answer (score 0):

I think what your are looking for is the Bean validation add-on. using it your can do something like adding @NotNull to your property and the generated field will automatically be marked as required.

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-bean-validation